# Rendering angular table conditionally issue using :enter and :leave animation transitions

Tags: angular, animation, angular-cdk

I am trying to collapse and expand angular cdk-table conditionally using *ngIf and :enter, :leave transitions.
The problem is that, the table is removing it's content before the animation finish. Other contents that are inside the *ngIf sibling elements with table are not removed until animation finished.

here is the html:

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="expanded = !expanded">
   Click To
   <span *ngIf="expanded">Collapse</span>
   <span *ngIf="!expanded">Expand</span>
</button>

<div class="expandable" *ngIf="expanded" [@detailExpand]>
    <div class="intro">this content will stay until animation finish</div>
    <table cdk-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="table">
       <!-- Position Column -->
       <ng-container cdkColumnDef="position">
          <th cdk-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>No.</th>
          <td cdk-cell *cdkCellDef="let element">{{element.position}}</td>
       </ng-container>

       <!-- Name Column -->
       <ng-container cdkColumnDef="name">
          <th cdk-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
          <td cdk-cell *cdkCellDef="let element">{{element.name}}</td>
       </ng-container>

       <tr cdk-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
       <tr cdk-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

[codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-orla-gwkmkh?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:285-295)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I've got the same issue.

Comment: i just came across a solution by myself, not removing the content immediately but  when time of animation finish.